# How much health does the Leechade spirit grant per hit?

Tags: bastion

In Bastion, after upgrading the shop, you can buy the spirit Leechade. This results in reduced potenecy of health tonics, but also grants health when striking foes. However, it doesn't specify how much health is gained per hit. I'm also uncertain as to whether this applies to all attacks, or just melee attacks. Consdering it costs a 1000 fragments, I'd prefer to know this before buying it.

How much health is restored per hit with Leechade? Also, does it apply to all attacks or just melee attacks?

[image]

Comment: Believe me, it is worth every penny.  Use it with weapons that can hit multiple enemies at once quickly (Scrap Musket, Dueling Pistols, Fire Bellows, Galleon Mortar and Calamity Cannon) and surviving "Who Knows Where" challenges with all idols activated becomes a heck more easier.

Comment: It somehow did not occur to me that the -Health Tonic Potency would be worth it in "Who Knows Where" with all idols (especially Roathus) activated! Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The health you get is not per hit, but rather a percentage of the damage you deal. From the numbers I've seen in-game, it looks like there's a progression:

- 20-39 damage = 1 HP
- 40-59 damage = 2 HP
- 60-79 damage = 3 HP

Basically, **it looks like you get 5% of the damage you deal as health, rounded down.**

Some test data from Who Knows Where:

- 34 = +1
- 42 = +2
- 50 = +2
- 62 = +3
- 78 = +3
- 112 = +5

Answer (score 10):

[Shaun's observation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/28456/how-much-health-does-the-leechade-spirit-grant-per-hit/28463#28463) of 5% is correct. You can verify this by looking at the entry for the Leechade entry in the game's PlayerUnits.xml file where it sets the `LifeSteal` attribute to `0.05`, or 5%. Additionally, this information is provided in the in-game description of the item, provided that you're playing the game in a language other than English. I'm not sure why it wasn't included in the English description.

As a side note, it seems that the 5% applies to pre-overkill damage, based on [Mana's testing](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1703726#1703726). Having bought this spirit myself, this gain seems to be worth the cost. In particular, when using this spirit with the Brusher's Pike, I was able to easily recover life in most scenarios without having to resort to healing manually.